# How to append the numpy lists of lists directly as columns to an existing CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a variable `value`:

```
value = [array([   3,    0,     1, -9999]),
         array([   1,    8,     5, -9999])]
```

How to write these values as separate columns `D, E, F and G`in pandas existing dataframe `data`. where `data` is

```
   A   B   C
0  2   6   1 
1  9   2   7
```

Expected Output:

```
    A   B  C  D  E  F  G
0   2   6  1  3  0  1  -9999
1   9   2  7  1  8  5  -9999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this works, who knew it was that simple!

```
df[['D', 'E', 'F']] = pd.DataFrame(value, index=df.index)
df        

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  2  6  1  3  0  1
1  9  2  7  1  8  5
```

Comment: Is there any fastest alternative? which avoids creation of an extra dataframe````df2````.

Comment: @Ganesh Okay, take a look.

Comment: I am getting this error: ````KeyError: "None of [Index(['D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"````

Comment: @Ganesh I should also mention this worked for me in pandas 1.0, so it's possible version incompatibility is also an issue.

Comment: May be. However, it worked when I added ````df[['D', 'E', 'F']] = pd.DataFrame(value)````. Thanks for the help!